# How to position a div next to element with absolute position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a `div` that can be attached to an element whenever user hover to the link

I have many links and my codes look like the following.

`for loops` to create many links

```
codes....

link.href='#';
link.innerHTML = 'test'
link.onmouseover = OnHover;

codes....


function OnHover(){
    var position;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className='testdiv';
        div.innerHTML = 'test';

        position=$(div).position();

        div.style.top = position['top'] + 15 + 'px';
        $(this).prepend(div);
}


    link element1
    link element2
 ----
|    |   //add new div when hover link element2
 ----
    link element2
    link element3



my css

.testdiv{
    position:absolute;
}
```

I want to add a new `div` everytime the user hover to my link and position on the `left top` of the element.

My code would position all the div on top instead of every element.

Are there anyway to do this? Thanks so much!

Comment: I think I might be able to help you with this; do you think you could create this using a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your other JavaScript/markup I can make the following observations:

- You need to set `position:absolute` on your new `div` before `top` will do anything.
- You need to make sure `link` is non-`position:static`.
- Non-dynamic styles like the above should be in your CSS, not JS.
- Positioning absolutely means you shouldn't need to use `$(div).position()`
- You're using a mix of jQuery and pure JavaScript which looks a little odd :)

**JS**

```
function OnHover() {
    var position;
    var div = $('<div></div>');
    div.addClass('testdiv');
    div.html('test');
    div.css('top', 15);
    $(this).prepend(div);
}
```

**CSS**

```
.testdiv {
    position:absolute;
}

a.testanchor {
    position:relative;
}
```